# `seaborn` `catplot` AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'markers'

Tags: python, seaborn, markers

I wanted to put marker symbols for `seaborn` `catplot`, but got the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'markers'
```

The whole code is [here](https://github.com/sjshtura/EWL-DUE/blob/master/Figure%209.ipynb).

```
markers1 = {'Demand': '>', 'Hardcoal': "s", 'Solar': '<', 'Wind_Onshore' : '.',
       'Wind_Offshore' : ',', 'Lit_Ion': '-', 'PSH':'#'}
#    {"Lunch": "s", "Dinner": "X"}


sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette(hue1))
ax = sns.catplot(x="intensities", y="values", data=df, s=10, size=5, hue='Technologie', palette=sns.color_palette(["#ADD8E6", "#414141", "#FFA500", "#fff340", "#00b8f2", "#a19595", "#f23333", "#2397fc"]))

ax.set_xticklabels(rotation = 45)

ax.axes[0][0].axhline(y = 0, ls='--', color='blue', markers = markers1, linewidth=2, alpha=.7)
```

[image: see here]

Comment: Did you try `sns.scatterplot`? It seems [sufficient for your needs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) and you can specify different marker types.

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Should be `marker`, not `markers`